# Development and Production License Key

Tags: upgrades

Is there a specific way I can have a development and live version of a website with Craft Pro running simultaneously.

We have multiple clients, and so using craft.dev for our development is not really feasible.

Can I duplicate the production license over to dev to unlock all features?

Comment: **UPDATE:** It's now possible to try Craft Pro from _any_ non-public domain: http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/test-craft-client-pro-from-any-non-public-domain

Comment: Hi Lindsey. I saw this on the blog yesterday and was hugely grateful it had been added. It really makes the craft development process a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We have multiple clients, and so using craft.dev for our development is not really feasible.

How about client1.craft.dev, client2.craft.dev etc?

Comment: I don't want to admit how long it took me to realize I could use subdomains of craft.dev. What a breakthrough that was!

Comment: We might be able to make this work, but we wouldn't be able to use them on our live server for group development. The old system was much more unrestricted at working in to any development environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy Craft on a local domain like "client1.dev" when you're building a site. When it's time to go live just *copy* the license.key file (app/config/license.key) to the production server (or vice versa).

You are allowed to use the same license on a public domain and on any number of private local domains like client1.dev. See [How is Craft’s license agreement enforced?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement) on the Craft docs for more info.